# Upload an image and refresh the img tag

Tags: java, spring, jetty, thymeleaf

Im am using Springboot and embedded server (Jetty) in my application.

I want to upload an image and reload my html page to show the new image in an img tag.

Th file is uploaded well and saved in a folder of my app. But when I reload my page, I can't see my new image.

It seems that my embedded server can't see my new files. When I rebuilt my project I can see the new file.

How can I do to refresh automatically my img tag without rebuilting my project

Here is my html page

```
<img th:src="@{/images/scan/}+${signatureScannedImg}" style="margin-bottom: 30px"/>
          <form th:action="@{/upload-signature-scan}" th:method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
              <tr><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td><input type="hidden" id="scannedFile" name="scannedFile" value="signature" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td><input type="hidden" id="idClient" name="idClient" th:value="${clientView.id}" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" /></td></tr>
            </table>
          </form>
```

And my controller method is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-signature-scan", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String handleFileUpload(
                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                 @RequestParam("idClient") Long idClient,
                                 @RequestParam("scannedFile") String  scannedFile,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Path rootLocation= Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/images/scan");
    try {
      Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), rootLocation.resolve("image.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", idClient);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("id", idClient);
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("signatureScannedImg", "image.jpg");
    return "redirect:/client/{id}/details";
  }
```

Comment: can we see your PictureUploadController class ?

Comment: yes I have change my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Thank you